# Prove this is an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

Here, o is a commutative integral domain. Maybe we can assume o is Noetherian.

$a,b \in o$. Prove the following sequence is exact.
$$0 \longrightarrow ao \longrightarrow ao + bo \longrightarrow o/(ao : bo) \longrightarrow 0$$

The question comes from Nagata's paper "A General theory of Algebraic Geometry Over Dedekind Domains II". I know $0 \longrightarrow bo \longrightarrow ao + bo$ is exact. But the other positions are difficult.

Comment: I think you mixed up $a$ and $b$ in the last expression. The hard part is to figure out what the map $ao+bo\rightarrow o/(ao\colon bo)$ even is supposed to be (it's not the inclusion followed by projection!), so I suggest you start there.

Comment: I have no idea what the map ao+bo→o/(ao:bo) is. My question is copied from the original paper, but it may contains some editorial errors.

Comment: Try some maps. It needs to send $ar+bs$ to $0$ if (and only if) $r=0$ and every $r\in o$ needs to be in its image (perhaps up to adding an element of $(bo\colon ao)$).

Comment: Thank you,  Thorgott. I figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of $a,b$ is 0, then the proof is easy.
So assume $a,b\not=0$.

The last map in the sequence should be
$$f: ao + bo \longrightarrow o/(ao:bo)$$
$$ as + br \mapsto r$$
To see $f$ is well-defined, if $as' + br' = as + br$, then $b(r'-r) = a(s-s')$. $r' - r \in (ao : bo)$. So $f(as' + br') = f(as + br)$.

Obviously, $f$ is surjective.

If $as + br \in \ker f$, then $r \in (ao:bo)$. Then $as + br \in ao$. So $\ker f = ao$.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right!